# Eliminar espacio blanco entre AppBar y NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, material-design, menu

Estoy teniendo problemas al ejecutar mi aplicación, me crea un espacio en blanco y no logro quitarlo. Este espacio solo aparece al ejecutar la aplicación por que en la pestaña diseño de Android Studio no se ve.
El espacio parece estar entre el  AppBarLayout y el MaterialToolBar, intente eliminando el AppBarLayout pero se elimina todo. Ya intente de todo y no veo solución, en código no tengo nada que genere alguna nueva vista, si ocupan ver algo especificamente puedo subirlo, gracias.

XML de mi activity Main

```html
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
            app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
            app:title="@string/appFirst" />


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="664dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardsContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_wave">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonCrochet"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tecnica Crochet"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.841"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.315" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="282dp"
                        android:layout_height="153dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/tejiendo" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola Intenta modificando tu atributo layout_heigh a 50dp

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
            app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
            app:title="@string/appFirst" />
```

Y agrega LayoutMargin_top=50dp a tu MaterialToolbar